# Apache Passenger module does not route certain file extensions to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, url-routing, passenger

I have installed mod_passenger (passenger-install-apache2-module) and have the following in my Apache configuration:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /var/www/html/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.24/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /var/www/html/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.24
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.2.2/ruby
</IfModule>

RackEnv production

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName domain.com
 # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
 <Directory /var/www/html/public>
 # This relaxes Apache security settings.
 AllowOverride all
 # MultiViews must be turned off.
 Options -MultiViews
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My Rails website is working however some URLs that end in .php or .txt do not get processed by Passenger resulting in a generic 404 page instead of the nicely formatted 404 page on my Rails site.

How can I route all file extensions to Passenger/Rails?

Or how can I make URLs that end in .php actually be processed by PHP.